# Printing an object array gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, object, exception, printing

```
public class StudentSchedular {

    private Student[] students=new Student[10];
    private int counterStudent;

    public String addStudent(int rollNumber,String name)
    {
        students[counterStudent++]=new Student(rollNumber,name);

        return "Student added successfully";
    }

    public void showAllStudents()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++){
            System.out.println(students[i].getRollNumber());
            System.out.println(students[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is a noob question..but still !
Here I have omitted the other getter/setter parts and other cases where I input the values for rollnumber and name. I am trying to print the object array, but it is giving an null pointer exception. I am inputting only 2 3 values and when I try to print, it gives NPE. I know this is because of null values being in the remaining index positions, I just needed a soln to print the whole object array !

Comment: You are not using addStudent() method anywhere, which you are intializing the array.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a `ArrayList` of students. It is easy to handle, that solves the problem also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get `NullPointerException` is because of `private Student[] students=new Student[10];`. It means that you have an `Student` array which has a fixed size of 10. Default `Object` values in Java is `null`. Without adding anything to the array it means you have 10 `null` objects in students.

If an offset in the students array is not filled yet, you will hit a null value and get an exception, because you try to invoke a method on `null`.

You can validate it in the loop:

```
        for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++){
            if(students[i] instanceof User) {
                System.out.println(students[i].getRollNumber());
                System.out.println(students[i].getName());
            }
        }
```

EDIT: This 'issue' can be avoided by using `List<User>` instead of `User[]`. But I can't decide for you if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the new **For loop** (since Java 5).

```
for(Student student : this.students) {

}
```

The new for loop works for [arrays and all iterables objects, like ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). You'll get only non-null objects.

*For answer your question, the best practice is:*

**Overriding toString()** in your Student Object.

```
@Override
public void String toString(){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    stringBuilder.append(this.rollNumber);
    stringBuilder.append(this.name);

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

And at your loop, just do

```
System.out.println(stundents[i]);
```

**println** handles null values as you want, and code turns clean.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has 10 slots. If 3 are given values, then you have 7 slots with null. You will need to either change the type of data structure you are using, or check for nulls when printing. The below code would do a null check and then print which index in the array contains the null value.

```
public void showAllStudents()
{
    for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++)
    {
        if(students[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(students[i].getRollNumber());
            System.out.println(students[i].getName());
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Array is null at index: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```